# Waterline stream callback not reachable

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I can't make waterline's `stream` work. I'm following [stream docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/stream).

**Am I using `stream` correctly?**

```
MyModel.stream({ isSubscribed: true }).populate("user").eachBatch(10, function(err, records){
   console.log("Code reached inside stream results")
})
// Output: Prints nothing
```

While the `find` function works very well

```
MyModel.find({ isSubscribed: true }).populate("user").exec(function(err, records){
   console.log("Found "+ records.length+ " records")
})
// Output: Prints "Found 12 records"
```

Update: The issue seems to be specific to `eachBatch` function. Not sure exactly what but tested `eachRecord` and that did work.

```
await MyModel.stream({ isSubscribed: true }).populate("user").eachRecord(async function(record){
   console.log("Code reached inside stream results")
})
// Output: Code reached inside stream results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Waterline `stream` docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/stream) were not helpful. After looking into [waterline code for stream](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/d14b72746c6331579037527198c10b8b1434cee6/lib/waterline/methods/stream.js) I edited my code as following and it worked i.e. the code inside the eachBatch callback is reachable now

```
MyModel.stream({ 
    isSubscribed: true 
}).eachBatch(function(records, next){ 
    console.log("Reachable!! Found records: ", records); 
    next(); 
}).exec(function(err){
   console.log("Done with stream query")
})
```